# Shared folder in OneDrive File Picker using JavaScript SDK

Tags: sdk, onedrive

Is it possible to have "Shared" folder (see attached screenshot) in One Drive File Picker using last version of JavaScript SDK?

Shared folder:

[image]

I looked through documentation but I can't find something related to my question. I assuming "sourceTypes" property can solve it but it seems there aren't presented all possible values for this property.

Thanks!